# How to deal with users who have reputation, but their accounts have been hijacked to spammers?

Tags: discussion, reputation, spam, account-suspension, virus

This just popped up:

> [image: spam via reputable account]

Notice that the [author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630184/rahul-sagore) has 26 points of reputation, so he's not about to lose much. Probably, this will get deleted pretty soon (I instantly flagged it as spam), but other users are still downvoting him.

Obviously, he has a computer security problem and his account should be locked; however, once he regains exclusive access to his account, he might find himself in a situation where his reputation was damaged due to spam flagging. How does SO deal with honest users whose accounts get hijacked?

Comment: @Chenmunka: hence, pretty sure

Comment: Granted.  But I think the issue with lost rep is common to both cases.

Comment: @Chenmunka: agreed!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention, or [report it directly to us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact). What we typically do:

- Contact the user using an email *not* associated with the compromised credentials if possible (if they have multiple emails, that is), otherwise reach out to them using the one we have
- Let them know that they need to secure their credentials, and their account
- Place the account in a network-wide suspension until we've heard back from them, to avoid further abuse of the account
- Invalidate all sessions that they currently hold (or, basically, log them out everywhere). This is effective when robots are using it.

Once we hear back from the user, we can disassociate the spammy stuff from their account, so there's no rep loss / black mark to speak of.

Comment: Good protocol - I don't have to worry so much someone could ruin my SE life :P